# Add frame by code

Tags: ros-hydro, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to know if it is possible add a new frame by code.

For example a node publishing a frame and modify the position and orientation. Something like static_transform_publisher but doing it by code.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202247/add-frame-by-code/) by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is explained in the [tf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials) and [tf2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials). You're looking for a *tf broadcaster*

---

Edit: or [Adding a frame (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2